# Is there a simple algebraic proof that stationary and independent increments imply a distribution which only depends on differences?

Tags: stochastic-processes

I read this section [here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_1_1_counting_processes.php) where they state "... This means that the distribution of the number of arrivals in any interval depends only on the length of the interval, and not on the exact location of the interval on the real line."

I though, there might be some simple algebraic proof for this, but it seems, you have to work quite a bit as described [here](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-PP.pdf)
(Thanks to this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/253186/209028))

**Precise question:**

**Definition 1 (stationary increments)**: A continuous-time random process $X(t)$ is said to have stationary increments
if for all $t_2\geq t_1 \geq 0$ and all $\tau \geq 0$: $(X(t_2)-X(t_1))$ and $(X(t_2+\tau)-X(t_1+\tau))$ have the same distributions.

**Definition 2 (independent increments)**: A continuous-time random process $X(t)$ has independent increments if,
for all $0 \leq t_1 < t_2 < t_3\dots < t_n$, the random variables $(X(t_2)-X(t_1)), (X(t_3)-X(t_2)), \dots, (X(t_n)-X(t_n−1))$
are independent.

**Claim**: For a continuous-time random process $X(t)$ with stationary and independent increments
$X(t_2)-X(t_1)$ and $X(t_2-t_1)$ have the same distributions.

(I think, there should be a counter example to the following: For a continuous-time random process $X(t)$ with stationary increments $X(t_2)-X(t_1)$ and $X(t_2-t_1)$ have the same distributions.)

Comment: Setting $t_1=0,$ $t_2=s_2-s_1,$ and $\tau=s_1$ (for $s_2\ge s_1\ge 0$ in definition (1) implies $X(s_2-s_1)-X_0=X(t_2)-X(t_1)$ and $X(t_2+\tau)-X(t_1+\tau)=X(s_2)-X(s_1)$ have the same distribution.  Aren't you assuming $X_0=0$ a.e.? If so, after rewriting "$s$" as "$t,$" what is left to show?

Comment: @whuber thank you for the hint! Yes, $X_0 = 0$. As I formulated the claim only in one direction, there should be nothing left to show? By construction $s_1$ and $s_2$ are arbitrary... Do I miss anything?

Comment: @whuber Then my second version would be correct, too. And independent increments are not necessary.

Comment: @Christoph: As you seem to have solved the problem you can answer it yourself now, in the answer box!